# IntelliJ IDEA: install plugins from command line

Tags: plugins, command-line, intellij-idea

Does IDEA provide a command line executable to edit some settings, install/uninstall plugins, etc without actually starting the IDE and clicking around?

For example, it is possible to install new plugins for Eclipse with:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository #{repo} -installIUs #{plugins}
```

Any equivalent for IntelliJ?

Comment: I haven't come across anything like this. Why would you need to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the installation of IDEA on a workstation (think Puppet or Chef script). I'd like to install a predefined set of plugins as part of the provisioning.

Comment: another use-case is to automate the IDEA installation for a docker-image

Comment: Really hoping for this to augment the [automatic installation using Puppet](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/63068217d797541e56b4a48001547963f25fa269/modules/integrated_development_environment/manifests/init.pp).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the workaround I found. To be clear: this is *not* what I was looking for, just the closest solution I found so far.

It is possible to download plugins for IntelliJ IDEA from the repository here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea_ce For example, here is the Scala plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347?pr=idea_ce . Each version has a direct link.

Once downloaded, extract the zip file in `~/.IdeaIC13/config/plugins` (dependent on the platform and the version of IntelliJ you are running of course).

That's it. With a shaky combination of `wget` and `unzip` it is possible to install a plugin via the command line. Clearly not a great solution: for my use case (ie provisioning a workstation via Chef) I need to know in advance the URL to a specific plugin and I need to know the version of IntelliJ (to identify the config folder in the user's home).

Comment: Thanks for the update @vptheron, definitely going to help with automating developer environment setup (my use case is for Docker).

Comment: @Brett running Intellij in a Docker instance... how did that turn out?

Comment: @MikeD was a little sluggish and we had 1 or 2 issues. A vanilla intellij works fine, so we ended up mapping the local workspace into the container and runing the IDE locally, with tooling running inside the container.

Comment: Link http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347?pr=idea_ce takes me to the scala plugin page but doesn't download anything.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at least for IntelliJ Idea 2020.3 anymore. I placed the zipfiles in `~/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/plugins` folder and unzipped.

Comment: For folks who are not able to find the directory mentioned in the answer, I was able to find it in ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaICxxxx.x/plugins

I was looking for doing this for Android Studio and in my case the directory was ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioXXXX/plugins

Answer (score 9):

Here is a one-liner to download/extract the latest version of a given plugin provided that you have `jq`, `bsdtar`, `wget` and `curl` in your PATH:

```
wget -qO-  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/$(curl https://plugins.jetbrains.com/api/plugins/4415/updates | jq -r '.[0].file') | bsdtar -xvf- -C ~/.PhpStorm2018.3/config/plugins
```

Replace the numeric plugin ID and output directory as needed. Restarting the IDE will show downloaded plugin(s) as being installed.

Answer (score 5):

`$> idea64 installPlugins yourPluginId`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sync plugins for members, you can use **Required Plugins**:

[image]

An error will pop up if no plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small bash to handle it:

```
pluginsIds=(
7499
20485
)
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea*/plugins || exit

for pluginId in "${pluginsIds[@]}"; do
  id=$(curl -s "https://plugins.jetbrains.com/api/plugins/$pluginId/updates" | jq -r '.[0].id')
  curl -L -o file.zip "https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=$id"
  echo "A" | unzip file.zip && rm file.zip
done
```