# How do I backup my IntelliJ plugins and automatically install them again?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, dotfiles

I was backing up my dotfiles and selected parts of my .idea directory. I recklessly removed a symlink in such a way that it deleted my plugins directory.

I didn't know all the plugins I had installed and I couldn't find a file containing a list of those plugins. **Does such a file exist?**

Essentially my goal is to:

1. backup my plugins in case `.idea` or `plugins` is accidentally deleted, or if I want to re-install IntelliJ and forgot the plugins I had installed.
2. have IntelliJ install the plugins automatically when I choose to restore them.

There are a few solutions I can think of:

- If a file containing a complete list of plugins exists then place it under version control.
- Place the entire plugins directory (which includes binaries) into version control. **This I want to avoid**.
- Instead of placing it under version control, place it under a backup directory. This should work as I just need to copy the files across into the plugins directory. The only problem I have is that it **separates my files and directories** unless I choose to place the entire selection of the .idea directory there.
- Export and Import settings from IntelliJ although I believe that the plugins need to be installed already as they are merely settings. The `.zip` file will give me an indication of the plugins I have installed **but I'd have to manually export my settings on every installation**.
- Keep a manual copy of my plugins and update it every time a new plugin is added. This could work because I don't install a lot of plugins but **I'd prefer to have it automated**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Settings Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync) feature which synchronizes your settings between different systems and stores the backup of the settings and the list of installed plug-ins in your JetBrains account.

`.idea` project directory should not have any relation to the plug-ins directory that is [stored under the user profile](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Another option is to use the [Required Plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/required-plugin.html) feature to store the list of the the plug-ins you need together with your project. Certain project files can be put into the [version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839).

Comment: Settings Sync is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Settings Sync is only available for Ultimate users. Doesn't apply to Android Studio or Community Edition users. "Required plugins" seems to be on a per project bases not IDE level

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use the functionality of [IDE settings sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) plugin.

This plugin is built into IntelliJ IDEA and allows you to bing your settings (like themes, keymaps, **plugins**, etc.) to your JetBrains account.

Another option is to store your plugins through a settings repository (same [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html)). It allows you to configure repository, where all your setting will be saved and automatically synchronized.

Comment: Settings repository doesn't sync the plug-ins at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143403.

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned to CrazyCoder, Settings Sync is exactly what I need to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

It is also possible to install plugins from command line
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#3f3fc196

in .bash_profile:

```
#open /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/
# https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#c668f7d8
idea () { open -n /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/ --args $* ;}
```

`idea installPlugins <PluginID>`

e.g. for https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18824-codeglance-pro
pluginid is `com.nasller.CodeGlancePro` (shown on page end)

```
idea installPlugins com.nasller.CodeGlancePro
```

So just document so in README or add script.

---

**Option 2**

If you want to sync plugins for members, you can use **Required Plugins** of specific project:

[image]

An error will pop up if no plugin:

[image]

See newer answer [IntelliJ IDEA: install plugins from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044513/intellij-idea-install-plugins-from-command-line)